# Como exibir imagem network no flutter via adnroid Studio?

Tags: flutter, dart, image, widget, background-image

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());

}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        title: const Text(
          'Photo Album',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
      drawer: const Drawer(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Fala Robson, bem vindo ao site. Poderia editar sua pergunta e adicionar alguns detalhes? Acho que se você fizer isso vai aumentar bastante suas chances de obter uma resposta. Por exemplo, o quê você já tentou fazer? Deu algum erro? Se sim, qual? O que você queria alcançar? Do jeito que a pergunta está atualmente parece que você quer algum tipo de tutorial e esse site acaba não sendo o lugar para isso.